# gimbal lock, can't solve by quaternion

Tags: android, sensors, quaternions, pitch

When device is rotated by some amount, a simple cube has to rotate by the same amount but in the opposite direction. For example, the cube has to rotate to 45 degrees to the left if the device is rotated 45 degrees to the right. Or when pitch is 30 degrees, the cube has to rotate -30 degrees around X axis. When the yaw is 10 degrees, the cube has to rotate -10 degrees around Z axis. I've used .getRotationMatrixFromVector followed by getOrientation like so:

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {

     SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
             mRotationMatrix , event.values);
     SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);
     azimuthVal =  (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]))*100.0)/100.0);
     pitchVal= (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]))*100.0)/100.0);
     rollVal = (Math.round((Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]))*100.0)/100.0);}
```

But the problem with it change in pitch affects roll and vice versa and as a result when device is rotated around X axis, the pinch value changes->roll changes -> the cube rotates not only around X but also around Y, when I don't need that.

I've looked around the internet and many refer to Quaternions as a solution but how can I apply quaternions to my specific application, as I need to know amount of degrees device is rotated by along an axes.

Comment: Do you just want the cube to reflect the device position but just in the opposite direction?

Comment: yes, if I understood you correctly, yes that's what I want to do

Comment: Then just pass the minus rotation matrix to your drawing method.

Comment: can you elaborate more on it please. do you mean using glRotate?

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenGl, but if you use glRotate to rotate an object then yes.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: no, i don't think i got you fully.  glRotatef(angle, x, y, z). where am i putting rotation matrix. Also, I don't see how does it solve gimbal lock

Comment: here is what i did: 
for(int i = 0; i < 16;i++)
            {
             mRotationMatrix[i]*=-1;
            }
and then i passed this to my drawing program. but it doesn't rotate in opposite direction but behaves rather strangely

Comment: I am pretty sure OpenGl has some kind of transform matrix that you pass in that would transform your image according to the matrix. As I said I do not know openGl and cannot help. Go read the android document about rotation matrix, there is one sentence that say something like you do not need to remap for OpenGl. For me the device coordinates are function of times, and rotation matrices tell me exactly what those coordinates are with respect to the world coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Gimbal lock happens when you want to extract (Euler) rotation angles from the rotation matrix, basically at some specific rotation we loose a degree of freedom in the equation between rotation matrix components and rotation angles and the actual rotation angles are not recoverable,

So in your code it may happen at :
SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);

You should somehow solve the issue before extracting the rotation angles,
this could be done by modifying the quaternion's components as is explained here:

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/